# How to transform a tertiary alcohol to a carboxyl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am trying to transform a lipid with a tertiary alcohol into a carboxylic acid.

More specifically, I want to convert to diplopterol (see below) into something homologous to cholesteryl hemisuccinate (see below).

**Any suggestions?**

*Diplopterol:*

[image]

*Cholesteryl hemisuccinate:*

[image]

Comment: I think you need to specify a bit more information on the specific tertiary alcohol and carboxylic acid that you want because a general tertiary alcohol, $\ce{R1R2R3COH}$, can retain only 1 of the 3 sidegroups and I guess it matters which one you want to keep. Just as a startup: direct oxidation is not an option, because there is no hydrogen available on the central $\ce{C}$

Comment: The compound I'm trying to convert is diplopterol: http://www.chemicalbook.com/CAS%5CGIF%5C1721-59-1.gif . I want to end up with something homologous to cholesteryl hemmisuccinate: http://www.goldbandchem.com/1510-21-0.htm

Comment: Ok. I assume you want to keep the big molecule and get rid of the methyl groups then

Comment: yeah, more or less, see edits to my previous comment...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that what you claim to want to do is what you actually want to do.

Cholesterol hemisuccinate is prepared from cholesterol, but not by converting the alcohol functional group into a carboxyl group. The alcohol oxygen becomes one of the oxygen atoms in the ester, but not the carboxyl oxygen. Cholesterol hemisuccinate can be prepared in the lab probably from cholesterol and succinic anhydride in the presence of a non-nucleophilic base (like pyridine or triethyl amine), which can act as a proton shuttle. An acidic workup will be needed to remove the base and protonate the carboxylic acid. The scheme below shows this reaction (sans acidic workup). The alcohol oxygen is highlighted in red.
[image]

An identical reaction could be done with your molecule, diplopterol. Dissolve both (1 eq) diplopterol and succinic anhydride (1.1 eq.) in dichloromethane or diethyl ether (or any low polarity aprotric solvent you like). Cool on an ice bath. With stirring, add pyridine (1.1 eq.) dropwise. Let the reaction warm to room temperature, probably about 2 hours. The product will likely precipitate as the pyridinium salt. Check the progress by TLC or some other means. The product will probably be more polar than the reactant. Work up by adding dilute HCl (probably 0.1 M). Extract the aqueous layer with your organic solvent of choice. Combine the organic layers. Wash with brine. Dry over magnesium or sodium sulfate. Remove the solvent by evaporation (rotary being preferred), and purify by chromatography if necessary.

Alternatively, if the product does precipitate at the pyridium salt, collect the salt by filtration, wash the precipitate with ether and then with cold ethanol (will wash away the reactants). Then, add the precipitate to the 0.1 M HCl and extract with ether if necessary. Further purification is probably not needed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try reaction with sodium acetate, anhydride acetic at 120°C for 6h for acetilation product. Because of tertiary alcohol, more hard condicions it´s needed.